# Google apps: tracking user email or name changes

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

I'm working on application, which uses google apps API. In my application google domain's admin can add users from domain and do some manipulation with them. This parts works well.

But google apps admin can change email or name of his domain's users. And here is the problem. I'm trying to investigate, what's the best way to figure out that user's email was changed. I was thinking that the best way is to check user's nicknames(when admin changes user's email his old email is attached to him as 'nickname'), but there's posibility to delete this nickname, so there can be nothing to check.

Which suggestions do you have?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace Google Provisioning API calls with the new [Directory Admin SDK API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users) calls. The new Directory API calls provide you with an [immutable ID](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users) (the id attribute) for user accounts that will not change when an admin renames the user's primary email address.

Comment: I just went here to answer on this question and write the same. So, looks like this API is exactly what I need.